# Use es6 Promise in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, promise, ecmascript-6

I am using NodeJS 6.9.1.
My command: node -e 'console.log(process.versions.v8);' 
Result: 5.1.281.84

When I want to use promise like that:

```
function updateTokenIfNeeded(){
    return new Pomise(function(resolve, reject){
        if(Cookie.value == ""){
            getToken()
            .then(function(res){
                Cookie.value = res;
                resolve();
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                reject(err);
            });
        }
    });
};
```

I got an error: "ReferenceError: Pomise is not defined"

What can I do?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You spelt promise wrong.

It's Promise not Pomise.

```
function updateTokenIfNeeded() {
    return new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {
        if (Cookie.value == "") {
            getToken()
                .then(function(res) {
                    Cookie.value = res;
                    resolve();
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                reject(err);
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Oh my god! I am so dumb !!!!!! Thanks

Comment: No problem, we've all been there before!